# Use comments as objects when importing CSV in RStudio

Tags: dataframe, rstudio, import-from-excel, import-csv

The CSV files i currently export begin with 5 rows which contain information about the data frame below it. For Example:

`#Date: 01/01/01`
`#Time: 01:01:01`
`#ID: 123`
`#Location: England`

*Data Frame Here*

Currently i import the csv by excluding all the comments which have '#' in front. However i find myself needing to create objects further down the line which contain the information held in the '#' above the dataframe.

Is there a way i can import the data frame from the csv and also have the comments import as object values? e,g Date = 01/01/01 etc

Comment: In which programming language are you going to achieve this? What have you researched/tried already to tackle that problem?

Comment: @Capricorn I'm a beginner on RStudio. I use the 'Import Dataset' button to get my csv import code. At the moment i have not found a way to make use of the comments above the dataframe as the import either excludes them or fails to correctly import the dataframe if the comments are not ignored.